# Java creating a waveform with samples

Tags: java, audio, arrays, waveform

I have loaded a sound file into a bytearray. I am confused at what I have to do next to get the information to plot the points for a waveform. From what I have found online I have to create another array? Can someone explain to me how this would work as I don't quite understand how the samples would be gathered.

Comment: What format is your soundfile? Is it raw wav format?

Comment: I am currently using .au though I do plan on trying .wav files.

Comment: *"I don't quite understand how the samples would be gathered."*  It depends on the [`AudioFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html).  E.G. A mono, 8 bit format will have 1 byte per frame.  Each byte will represent the amplitude of the waveform.

Comment: "I have loaded a sound file into a bytearray.": loaded how? Using an input stream, or using the Java sound API?

Comment: I have used the AudioInputStream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples are gathered according to the file format.
Lets just say, your audio format is a 8 bit one channel audio file.

This is the simplest case. You can just iterate trough your byte[] and draw the stored values as amplitude.

When your file is a 16bit audio file, each sample consists of 2 bytes, so you'll have to take a look at two bytes for each sample. You can do this by calling the following method:

```
private int getSixteenBitSample(int high, int low) {
    return (high << 8) + (low & 0x00ff);
}
```

It will concatinate the first and the second byte of your bytearray for each sample.
So your loop would look somehow like this:

```
int sampleArray[] = new int[numSamples];

for(int i = 0, j=0;i < bytearray.length;)
{
    int iLow = bytearray[i];
    i++;
    int iHigh = bytearray[i];
    i++;

    sampleArray[j] = getSixteenBitSample(iHigh, iLow);
    j++;
}
```

The third case could be, that your file is a 16 bit stereo audio file. In that case each sample has two bytes, and after each byte the channel changes.

For example:

```
First read sample 1 from byte 0 and byte 1. -> First sample of channel 1
Second read sample 2 from byte 2 and byte 3 -> First sample of channel 2
Third read sample 3 from byte 4 and byte 5 -> Second sample of channel 1
Forth read sample 4 from byte 6 and byte 7 -> Second sample of channel 2
```

For further and mor detailed description, take a look at [this page](http://book.javanb.com/swing-hacks/swinghacks-chp-10-sect-7.html)